# elementary OS included software

Tags: elementary-project

why doesn't elementary OS include applications like libreoffice, task manager or create office applications "by own" to be more exclusive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also, Libreoffice takes a lot of space. This contributes to making the iso smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I think because the project purpose is not to be exclusive...
Moreover, having to download software by hand as a user force you to be aware of the necessity of the software you're searching, it does gratify the developpers.